# Uploading imageFile to server android

Tags: android

Iam trying to upload image files to server. First i locally store the image path in the  database and then  create a new file using the path and try to upload the images using http post request. It is working fine for only 2 to 3 image file and if i try to upload continuously more than 3 image files one after the other the files are not uploaded. I have a very basic idea in networking.Plz kindly give me a solution.

Comment: `and then create a new file using the path`. Why would you create a new file if you have already a file that you want to upload?

Comment: im storing the records of images in sqlite database. I have a list view which displays list of images from the database and a upload button for each list item. when i click the upload button it creates a temp file  using the path in the database which i use to upload to the server using http post request.

Comment: `the records of images`. What is a record of an image? `it creates a temp file using the path in the database`. If you store only a path in the database then your image is still on 'file system'. So why create a temp one? Please be more exact describing what you do and what actually happens.

Comment: user can choose image from gallery or take a image using camera which can be cropped and stored in device external storage as a file.In database i have a table for images which is used to store details about all these images. I have to upload only files directly. I dont know about any method which directly takes a file from external storage in device,so using the path in the database i create a temp file and sending to the server as a file.

Comment: `I dont know about any method which directly takes a file from external storage in device,so using the path in the database i create a temp file`. What is the difference in using a temp file path and an external storage path? Nothing. Your upload funtion only needs a path. I do not understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to work like this

```
public void connectForMultipart() throws Exception {
    con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(url)).openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    con.connect();
    os = con.getOutputStream();
}

public void addFormPart(String paramName, String value) throws Exception {
    writeParamData(paramName, value);
}

public void addFilePart(String paramName, String fileName, byte[] data) throws Exception {
    os.write( (delimiter + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + paramName +  "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write("\r\n".getBytes());

    os.write(data);
    
    os.write("\r\n".getBytes());
}   
public void finishMultipart() throws Exception {
    os.write( (delimiter + boundary + delimiter + "\r\n").getBytes());
}
```

## for getting response

```
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));



String sResponse;
while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) 
 {
     s = s.append(sResponse);
 }

 if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
 {
     return s.toString();
 }else
 {
     return "{\"status\":\"false\",\"message\":\"Some error occurred\"}";
 }   
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In place of image you can send anything(in your case its `image` file), you would like to... if it creates some heck then
you should divide the large file into small parts then try to sending.And Join this small part on the server.

In my case `httpmime-4.2.1-1.jar` is only needed in this code
[image]

Answer (score 0):

refer this

[Image Upload and Retrieve Android with WebServices (PHP Code)](https://github.com/angtwr31/imguploadretreive)

The Repository contain 2 Android project .. Image Upload to Mysql and Image Retreival from Mysql
one folder contain webservices and mysql database

for Image Upload ... you only need insert.php

> Let me if it wasn't worked

Comment: using Sqlite database for android.

Comment: can you ellaborate ...what you are trying to say?

Comment: client side coding only

Comment: UploadImageToDB folder in this repository containing project for uploading image to Database (remote database server)..........

Answer (score 0):

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //follwing line compress Bitmap image
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    String s= Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

here you will get a base64 encoded image, just send String s to server. you can decode image from server.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one it will help you.

```
try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
        //FileBody bin = null;
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap2;

        if(rotatedBitmap2 != null){
            Random generator = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = generator.nextInt(n);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            rotatedBitmap2.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data,"dcc/"+n+".jpg");

            reqEntity.addPart("Image", bab);            
        }               
        post.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        if (resEntity != null) {
            //do some work
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }       
}
```